# Combining "aggregate" with a user-made function

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I am trying to extract information from a dataset of climatic variables (daily values), spanning multiple years. Presence and absence of snow is coded as 1 and 0 in the data set. Each line corresponds to a day and I have a columns cody for date and half year. 
For each half year period I am attempting to find the value of the date after the last occurence of snow presence (1). I tried this by grouping the variables via aggregate, but the use of a custom function did not succeed, since "aggregate" seems to pass the columns of the dataframe without a name.

```
dates<-c("1993-01-01","1993-01-02","1993-01-03","1993-01-04","1993-01-05","1994-02-20","1994-02-21","1994-02-22","1994-02-23","1994-02-24")
df<-data.frame(Date=as.Date(dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
               halves=as.factor(c(1993-01-01,1993-01-01,1993-01-01,1993-01-01,1993-01-01,1994-01-01,1994-01-01,1994-01-01,1994-01-01,1994-01-01)),
               plot1=c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
               plot2=c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0),
               plot3=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0))
```

I know that using loops is not that efficient, but since I want to avoid applying the function to the "not-plot-columns" I am using:

```
for(plots in names(df)[- which(names(df) %in% c("Date","halves"))]){        
     meltday[[plots<-aggregate(df[[plots]]~halves,df,df$Date[last(which(snow.days.half$Date==0)) + 1])  
}
```

This produces a error, since the last part is not evaluated as a function.
So I tried with a home-made function to find the Date+1 of the last occurence of 1 in all plot colums.

```
snowmelt<-function(x)
{snowmelt<-max(x[[Date]][x[[plots]]==1])
 snowmelt}
```

But then trying

```
for(plots in names(df)[- which(names(df) %in% c("Date","halves"))]){        
  meltday[[plots]]<-aggregate(df[[plots]] ~ halves,df,snowmelt)  
}
```

left me with an error statement, since the function coerces its input to a list.

So, I am quite stuck and will be very thankful and apprechiative for any comments or answers that point me into the right direction. 
My desired output would be a dataframe with dates in it: along the lines of

```
   >meltday
   halves         plot1       plot2         plot3
   1993-01-04     1993-01-04  1993-01-03    1993-01-05
   1994-01-01     1994-02-22  1994-02-24    1994-02-23
```

EDIT: added desired output for clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a preference for plyr, dplyr or data.table? Those are three packages that could help you perform this task.

Comment: I have no preference, tryed something with dplyr in this problem, but did not manage -.-: `df%>% group_by(halves) %>% mutate(Snow.Melt = Date[last(which(df[[plots]]==0)) + 1])` -

Comment: how should your desired output look?

Comment: edited the question to specify, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`

I changed the way you input the `halves` variable in the OP to use a character vector (I think that might've been a bug)

```
dates<-c("1993-01-01","1993-01-02","1993-01-03","1993-01-04","1993-01-05","1994-02-20","1994-02-21","1994-02-22","1994-02-23","1994-02-24")
df<-data.frame(Date=as.Date(dates,format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
               halves=as.factor(c('1993-01-01','1993-01-01','1993-01-01','1993-01-01','1993-01-01','1994-01-01','1994-01-01','1994-01-01','1994-01-01','1994-01-01')),
               plot1=c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
               plot2=c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0),
               plot3=c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0))
```

Then I use the `gather` command to put the data into a long-format, which I then turn into a grouped data-frame for which the `summarise` function can aggregate for each `plot`. I put the data back into a wide-format using `spread`.

```
df %>%
gather(plot, snow, plot1:plot3) %>%
group_by(plot, halves) %>%
arrange(Date) %>%
summarise(meltday=Date[max(which(snow==T))+1]) %>%
spread(plot, meltday)
```

The output is

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
      halves      plot1      plot2      plot3
*     <fctr>     <date>     <date>     <date>
1 1993-01-01 1993-01-04 1993-01-03 1993-01-05
2 1994-01-01 1994-02-22 1994-02-24 1994-02-23
```

Note: this will have an error if the meltday hasn't occurred (i.e. there is snow in the final entry). I haven't thought of a neater way to detect the 'last' snow day yet.

Comment: Thank you very much! One question further, though: how can one output the results of `spread(plot,meltdate)` as a dataframe?

Comment: You can add `%>% as.data.frame()` at the end ... and the above code can be used as an assignment e.g. `meltday_df <- df %>% ... (the rest)`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to define the following function to compute the `Date` after the last snow day:

```
date.after.last.snow <- function(x, Date) {
  Date[tail(which(x==1),1)+1]
}
```

Then use this function to summarize each `plot` column `group_by` `halves`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(halves) %>% 
              summarize_each(funs(date=date.after.last.snow(.,Date)),-Date)
```

The results using your data is as expected:

```
print(res)
### A tibble: 2 x 4
##      halves plot1_date plot2_date plot3_date
##      <fctr>     <date>     <date>     <date>
##1 1993-01-01 1993-01-04 1993-01-03 1993-01-05
##2 1994-01-01 1994-02-22 1994-02-24 1994-02-23
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(8401, 8402, 8403, 8404, 8405, 
8816, 8817, 8818, 8819, 8820), class = "Date"), halves = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1993-01-01", 
"1994-01-01"), class = "factor"), plot1 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0), plot2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), plot3 = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Date", "halves", "plot1", 
"plot2", "plot3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
##         Date     halves plot1 plot2 plot3
##1  1993-01-01 1993-01-01     1     1     0
##2  1993-01-02 1993-01-01     1     1     1
##3  1993-01-03 1993-01-01     1     0     1
##4  1993-01-04 1993-01-01     0     0     1
##5  1993-01-05 1993-01-01     0     0     0
##6  1994-02-20 1994-01-01     1     1     1
##7  1994-02-21 1994-01-01     1     1     1
##8  1994-02-22 1994-01-01     0     0     1
##9  1994-02-23 1994-01-01     0     1     0
##10 1994-02-24 1994-01-01     0     0     0
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about `summarise_each()` - nice one.